# How to split binary-delimited binary file?

Tags: awk

I’m trying to split a binary file by a binary delimiter… but awk is not happy with me... anyone happen to know what I’m doing wrong?

```
awk '/\x7c\x7c/{n++}{print >"out" n ".bin" }' input.bin
```

This results in:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    /\x7c\x7c/{n++}{print >"out" >>>  n <<<  ".bin" }
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

The delimiter is `||` which is `7c 7c` in hex. According to the awk docs, that should become `\x7c\x7c` for awk.

I also tried this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=""; FS=/\x7c\x7c/ } { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print $i > i }' input.bin
```

which resulted in the correct number of files, but some of the data was missing. The total file size of the split files was smaller than the original file (108 bytes total from a 2.2KB source file). So definitely not right.

Comment: That error message is from the lack of parens on the right of `>` as @null... stated, but you would not get that error from GNU awk and awk is a tool for handling text files not binary files with gawk being the only awk I know that can handle binary files but to make that work you need to set BINMODE. Get gawk and see the GNU awk manual.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just wrap the file name in `()`

```
awk '/\x7c\x7c/{n++}{print > ( "out" n ".bin" ) }' input
```

The parentheses are required because `awk` doesn't have any explicit concatenation operator. So we need to tell the `awk` that anything from `(` here to there `)` has to be concatenated.

For more info, please refer to  [string concatenations in awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Concatenation.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following splits by setting the "record separator" and should therefore work for very large files (assuming the "records" are not too large):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="\x00"; RS="\\|\\|"; n=0; }
     { n++; print >> "out" n ".bin" }'
```